# sort a file and get the first three words alphabetically in python

Tags: python, file, sorting

So I'm trying to print the first three words alphabetically from a text file. I know I need to sort the file first so its in alphabetical order and I tried this:

```
def top_three_by_alphabet(fileName):
 lines = f.readlines()
 lines.sort()
 print ('The first three words alphabetically in the file are' +
 str(line[:3])
print top_three_by_alphabet(f)
```

with this I'm getting a syntax error on my final print statement

Comment: Looks like `line[:3]` should be `lines[:3]`, but this will print the first three lines I think; not the first three words.

Comment: You don't need `print` in the last line. The method `top_three_by_alphabet` already has a print inside it.

Comment: This errors are trivial: Parameter 'fileName' value is not used, name should be lowercase. Unresolved reference 'f' and 'line'. Execute your code. Try it online: https://repl.it/EXvN/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call print on your function, since it's printing itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis on your "print" function, and a typo on lines/line.

```
def top_three_by_alphabet(fileName):
    lines = [line.strip() for line in open(fileName) if not line.isspace()]
    lines.sort()
    print ('The first three words alphabetically in the file are' +
    str(lines[:3]))

top_three_by_alphabet(f)
```

Comment: ok so now I have it printing but it prints "The first three words alphabetically in the file are ['\n', '\n', '\n'].

Comment: I added a list comprehension step to remove lines that are entirely whitespace, and remove trailing/leading whitespace from the rest.

Comment: Yea I'm getting an I/O operation on closed filed error

Answer (score 0):

You open a ( after your first print statement, but then don't close it

Answer (score 0):

And you also should send filename to your function, `print top_three_by_alphabet('yourfilename')` instead of `print top_three_by_alphabet(f)`

Answer (score 0):

### Small tutorial

How to read a file, line by line, using "utf8" encoding:

```
import io

filename = "path/to/file.txt"
with io.open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.rstrip()  # drop the newline
        print(line)
```

How to sort a collection (iterable):

```
coll = ["acb", "bac", "cab", "fac", "dac", "gag", "abc"]

# using a sorted iterator:
for item in sorted(coll):
    print(item, end=" ")
print()
# -> abc acb bac cab dac fac gag

# sorting a list
coll.sort()
print(coll)
# -> ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'cab', 'dac', 'fac', 'gag']

# using a criterion
coll.sort(key=lambda i: i[::-1])
print(coll)
# -> ['cab', 'acb', 'bac', 'dac', 'fac', 'abc', 'gag']
```

Putting all thing together:

```
with io.open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf8") as fd:
    for line in sorted(fd):
        line = line.rstrip()  # drop the newline
        print(line)
```

Splitting the words:

```
# The lazy way:
text = "The quick, brown, fox jumps *over* the lazy dog"
parts = text.split()
first_three_words = " ".join(parts[:3])
print(first_three_words)
# -> The quick, brown,

# using RegEx
import re

text = "The quick, brown, fox jumps *over* the lazy dog"
split_words = re.compile("\W+", flags=re.DOTALL).split
parts = split_words(text)
first_three_words = " ".join(parts[:3])
print(first_three_words)
# -> The quick brown
```

Comment: No need to import io. Open() and close() are given without the need to import them.

Comment: @Tyg13: using `io.open` is a "Best Practice" for people who want Python 2/Python 3 compatible code.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code will give you the first three **Lines**, to get the first three **words** you should do something like this:

```
def top_three_by_alphabet(file):
data = file.readall()
data = data.split(" ")   # Gets every word isolated
data.sort()
print ('The first three words alphabetically in the file are' + str(data[:3]))

print top_three_by_alphabet(file)
```

hope its helpful!

Comment: You should pass `file` not `fileName`. Or you should open the file inside function first.

Comment: My mistake, I fixed it